# How does JDBC4 connection.isValid happen in PgConnection?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-actuator, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application which uses spring actuator to do healthcheck, This does a healthcheck on db as well in my case it is postgres. Every once in a while i get this error in healthcheck

```
{"status":"DOWN","details":{"database":"PostgreSQL","error":"org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: StatementCallback; SQL \[SELECT 1\]; ERROR: unable to read data\\n  Detail: child connection forced to terminate due to client_idle_limit:60 is reached; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unable to read data\\n  Detail: child connection forced to terminate due to client_idle_limit:60 is reached"}
```

According to my understanding whenever a connection is borrowed for healthcheck that connection should already be valid connection using `connection.isValid()` jdbc4 api. But in my case that connection is not active and as soon as health check makes the query it got the client_idle_limit and the health check fails.

I verified every time a connection is borrowed `isValid` api is getting called, but i am unsure how that is working in case of pgjdbc as it is creating a `PreparedStatement` with empty string and that is not getting executed in postgres server.(Verified by request logs in pg server) I am assuming that `isValid` is always returning `true`.

https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgConnection.java#L1487

One possible solution is to use setting spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTestQuery which hikari docs explain to not use as they have already built some optimisation to not call postgress unecessarily to validate connection

Thank you